# How to Create SSH tunnel to do port forwarding with putty to a remote MySQL-db w/o server setup?

Tags: mysql, ssh, portforwarding, tunneling

I want to SSH connect to a REMOTE MySQL db by pointing to, say, the LOCAL 3306 port; so far, I was able to do so by:

1. Installing/setting up FreeSSHd in the remote server (Windows 7).
2. Create an SSH tunnel and do port forwarding using [putty.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) in the local
   machine (Windows 8.1)

I followed the instructions of these two articles here (in spanish, sorry :/ ):

1. [FreeSSHd on the server](http://www.redeszone.net/windows/freesshd-para-windows-instalacion-y-manual-de-configuracion-de-freesshd-para-windows-servidor-ssh-y-sftp/)
2. [SSH tunneling](http://www.redeszone.net/redes/ssh-tunneling/)

I've heard somewhere that if the remote server is running on Linux the step 1 is not always required. Do you guys know if there's a way/weird-trick to skip step 1 (setting up anything on the remote server, rather than installing MySQL Server)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh I see why this is not possible: It looks like some Linux distros come with a program similar to FreeSSHd by default, and there for, you can skip installing other tools on the server though now I'm sure the configuration will be always required anyways.